# Remove Quotation Marks From MongoDB String

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, discord.js

I want to store a value in the mongodb like `member.guild.name` or `${member.guild.name}` but the quotes turn it into a string so when im outputting it, it returns as member.guild.name or ${member.guild.name} instead of the guilds name, how would i counteract this issue?

Comment: At the moment this doesn't sound related to Mongo. It sounds like you have some problem with the data you prepare for Mongo, and as such that would likely happen with any database, or even simple file storage. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please show how you write and save the data to Mongo

Comment: Heres the Schema : https://pastebin.com/GLE7Hj74
Heres how im sending it : https://pastebin.com/eCAXbpKQ

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to make a welcome message in mongodb? and i've look at your code and you're calling things wrong, this will most likely fix your problem:

**Your Schema:**

```js
const guildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    welcome: {
        message: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            allowNull: true,
            default: `Hey ${member.user.name}, welcome to **${member.guild.tag}**!`,
        },
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model(`guild`, guildSchema);
```

***To:***

**Changed Schema:**

```js
const guildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    welcome: {
        message: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            allowNull: true,
            default: `Hey ${member.username}, welcome to **${message.guild.name}**!`,
        },
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('guild', guildSchema);
```

Comment: there was a typo in my schema here is the right schema: https://pastebin.com/tiXaV7vk

Comment: um.. apostrophe? those things that youre trying to call wont get called at all

Comment: i cant use backtics because member isnt defined in the schema

Comment: then do it instead on your message event

Comment: how would i do that?